# DNS Server Linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I've got a problem with my bind server... I can't find "/etc/default/syslogd" to add to it "SYSLOGD=”-a /var/lib/named/dev/log”

Two days ago, I setup whole Bind9 on my server, the domain works fine for 2 days, after two days it doesn't work... I dig my 2 dns and it seems to look empty...

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 60327
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.[mydomain].com.        IN  A

;; Query time: 3416 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec  3 22:29:01 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 34
```

and I think that is because I don't setup this syslogd... What I did is just :

*Installed bind9 on the server

*I add my domains to /etc/bind/named.conf

*I created domain file with information such as :

It's not full, just DNS part

```
@ IN NS ns1.[DomainName].com.

@ IN NS ns2.[DomainName].com.

@ IN A [MyServerIP]

ns1 IN A [MyServerIP]

ns2 IN A [MyServerIP]
```

*Than I create Vhost for the domain.

And I think that's it.

2 whole days it was working. Now it doesn't

What you suggest I should do ?

Comment: Please do not cross post Q's on multiple SE sites. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103564/dns-server-linux

Answer (score 1):

Your bind run in a chrooted environment, it is an obsolete way to get the illusion of the security, and makes your work much harder.

I suggest to disable the bind chrooting, because it is the cause of your problem and not some syslogd, etc. options.